# On Line Man Pages from Terminal

Tags: linux, debian, man, documentation

With the risk of raising a question that might already have an answer, i would like to ask if anybody knows if and how is it possible to read man pages in my terminal for programs/apps that are not installed in my system using online sources/online tools.

I made a stackexchange and google search but found nothing about this issue.

For example `man grep` will raise the grep manual as expected.
On the other hand `man agrep` will give an error since `agrep` is not installed.
In order to read `agrep manual` i have to `google agrep man pages` , getting results like this : https://linux.die.net/man/1/agrep

PS: BTW it seems strange to me that http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/dir_all_alphabetic.html do not provide agrep...

I wonder if it is possible to run `man agrep` or similar command from my terminal (without installing agrep) and read agrep man pages in terminal as usual man works.

I don't expect all man pages of the world to be locally available; i just wonder if there is any tricky way to use man (or even other command) to search and display man pages of not installed progs without having to open browser, type keyword, search in results etc.

PS: As noticed by Kusalananda, raising web queries may lead to results not suitable for particular distro version (different versions result will pop up). So the best (in my dream) would be if there was a kind of Distro specific (Debian in my case) internal / built in command (or even a switch) that could retrieve online man pages specifically for my setup (i.e something like : `man --online agrep` or `onlineman agrep`). It seems not.

Comment: The first thing to understand is that each package is normally responsible in maintaining its man pages so that they stay coherent with the installed version.  Some systems will install a generic list of man pages but they will ***fortunately*** never include all the man pages in the world.

Comment: Your current Google search is a good solution imo.

Comment: @JuliePelletier I was not expecting all the man pages of the world to be locally available... i look for a tricky way to call man (or other command maybe) to load man pages from online sources , without having to open my broswer, go to google, type the keyword, etc. Maybe what i say is just a dream.

Comment: There are dozens of ways to make a simple shell script to do that, but I doubt anyone spent more than 10 minutes on the subject, since having a browser open and doing a Google search is usually as fast as typing the command.

Comment: Under debian there is a package called `debian-goodies` which is a bunch of some sh/bash scripts. In there there is a script called `debman` that does exactly this work : downloads a deb package in a tmp directory (using `debget` script from the same bunch of scripts), and then extracts man pages out of this deb package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `links` : `links -dump https://linux.die.net/man/1/agrep | less` . Just change the category and name and you're good.

Comment: OMG, that's really ingenious.

Comment: @schaiba If we tie this to a script, will be almost perfect (i can do that...). There is a kind of failure due to the web site (die.net), since die.net does not provide some /a lot of man pages (i.e yad). I think in my dream i imagine a script that could locate man pages for almost any command...  Maybe the script i imagine of should poke the web to locate the man page requested...

Comment: Maybe the Google Custom Search API might be of some interest.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou Just a question: How would you ensure that you got the manual for what's installed on your system, or even a manual that was relevant to your flavour of Unix? Some utilities have the same name on different systems, but very different semantics. Sometimes an online manual might describe extensions that aren't even available on the system you're interested in. Are you even concerned about versions and outdated manuals?

Comment: @Kusalananda You have a very good point there. To be honest, my question was targeting to the hope of existence of a built in command (or even a switch) to be used let's say on Debian . I imagined that something like this could exist and i am not aware of : `man --online yad or agrep or whatever` . Apparently there is not such a built in tool, thus poking the web has the problems you are referring to.

Comment: @Kusalananda Or in case we make use of Google Api, we could first `apt list agrep` to get agrep version available for our distro, then search web for `agrep 4.17-9 man pages` and then display man page for particular version.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou Ho hum... At that stage, you might just as well pull the manual out of the package itself.

Comment: Why pipe into `less`? `links` itself has a paging capability.

Comment: how about a shell script that takes the command as an argument, then runs a curl command to search google for "linux man page "+command and submit via the "i'm feeling lucky" button then retrieve the returned URL ?

Comment: @Gilles : not with `-dump` it doesn't.

Comment: @ivanivan Sounds good idea.... I'm not sure if i could manage such curl script....If you have found /develop similar coding, let me know...

Comment: @schaiba Sure: use `links https://linux.die.net/man/1/agrep`. No `-dump` and no `| less`.

Comment: @schaiba Answer accepted. I was not familiar with `links` nice capabilities. Online man pages read with links is a nice and quick solution. For distro specific solutions (i.e case of different versions) maybe extractig man page out of the installation package as described bellow is more safe, but requires tools with particular capabilities (like apt-get --print-uris and dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile) .

Answer (score 3):

If this were Ubuntu, you could use the `dman` command from the `bikeshed` package. From [`man dman`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/dman.1.html):

```
dman   is   a   script   that   remotely   retrieves   manpages    from
http://manpages.ubuntu.com, but reads them on the local system.

This  is  often  useful  to read a manpage of a utility that you do not
have installed on the local system.

It will cycle through each manpage section available for a given TOPIC.
```

IIRC, `dman` is a script, so it might be possible to modify it to work with https://manpages.debian.org.

Comment: Very interesting script. Seems not easy to port it for Debian due to the different implementation /different format of  debian manpages  web site (based on a cgi-script that runs on server  without static pages support).

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, you might consider the [lynx text browser](http://lynx.browser.org/) instead.  That way, you need only enter:

```
lynx https://linux.die.net/man/1/agrep
```

It's worked for me in many situations, and appears to be widely available in software repositories for many systems.

As far as knowing you got the version for your system, I don't think there's any way to do that without getting the version number from the one you have installed, and looking in the man page you're trying to read.

Comment: For installed apps simple man is fine, we don't need online man. For not installed apps we could retrieve the version of the package with apt list...

Comment: Ah, my misunderstanding.  Yes, 'apt list' or equivalent for other distributions would be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Using online services to display manuals is cool, but as soon as i read @Kusalananda comment about pulling man pages out of installation packages, i got somehow obsessed to implement this technique that will ensure that i will read the correct manual for my distro.

The only bug in bellow solution is that it is based on recent versions of apt/dpkg that are available in Debian Testing 8.6 and might not be available in other systems.

**Extract the man pages from .deb files without download**
Locate the deb file like if you had plans to install the package in question (i.e yade):

```
apt-get --print-uris download yade
'http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/pool/main/y/yade/yade_2016.06a-7_amd64.deb' yade_2016.06a-7_amd64.deb 1621148 SHA256:26c0d84484a92ae9c2828edaa63243eb764378d79191149970926aa3ec40cdd4
```

PS: --print-uris switch prints the url of deb package but deb is not downloaded.

Find the man pages hidden in this deb file:

```
dpkg -c <(curl -sL -o- http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/pool/main/y/yade/yade_2016.06a-7_amd64.deb) |grep "man/man" |grep -vE "\/$" |awk '{print $NF}'
./usr/share/man/man1/yade-batch.1.gz
./usr/share/man/man1/yade.1.gz
```

Read the man page yade.1.gz (without downloading the deb):

```
man <(dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile <(curl -sL -o- http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/pool/main/y/yade/yade_2016.06a-7_amd64.deb) |tar -xO ./usr/share/man/man1/yade.1.gz)
```

man page is displayed correctly using man application.

```
apt --version --> apt 1.4~beta2 (amd64)
dpkg --version --> Debian 'dpkg' package management program version 1.18.18 (amd64).
man --version --> man 2.7.6.1
tar --version --> tar (GNU tar) 1.29
curl --version --> curl 7.51.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.51.0 GnuTLS/3.5.7 zlib/1.2.8 libssh2/1.7.0 nghttp2/1.17.0 librtmp/2.3
```

**Alternative way by downloading deb file:**
Bellow method based on classic apt-get, ar and tar should work in any distro.
deb file is downloaded in current working directory, man page is extracted and then file is removed.

```
pkg="$1"
apt-get download "$pkg" 2>/dev/null
debname=$(find . -name "$pkg*.deb")
datatar=$(ar t "$debname" |grep "data.tar") 
#ar t prints out the contents of the archive 

if [[ ${datatar##*.} == "gz" ]];then #extension check 
  options="z"
elif [[ ${datatar##*.} == "xz" ]];then
  options="J"
else
  echo "data.tar archive inside deb is not a gz or xz archive. Exiting"
  exit 1
fi

manpage+=($(ar p $debname $datatar | tar t"$options" |grep "man/man" |grep -vE "\/$" |awk '{print $NF}')) #tar t lists the files included in archive
man <(ar p "$debname" "$datatar" | tar xO"$options" ${manpage[@]}) 
#ar p and tar -O prints archive files / contents in stdout to be read by man
rm -f $debname #or rm -i for more control.
```

**Using manpages.debian.org**
As a third alternative, as of January 2017 somebody can use an alias / script that will pull the man page from debian nline, based on the fresh new debian manpages website which jumps you directly to the correct / most recent man page of the package you want:

```
alias debman='function __debman { links -dump https://manpages.debian.org/jump?q=$1 |awk "/Scroll to navigation/,0" |less; };__debman'
```

call it by terminal as `$ debman yade`

Comment: The simple approach is to set up a VM (I use a Vagrant box running directly on my Mac) and just install all the software packages whose man pages you are interested in.  (Why get all complicated?  Just use a VM.)

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou I would agree with Wildcard here. It's easier to just install the package, either locally or on a virtual machine. If you'd like to improve the script, then run it though [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) and use something like `apt-get download` rather than `curl` for downloading (`apt --print-uris` doesn't work on Ubuntu AFAIK).

Comment: @Kusalananda Curl is not actually downloading the deb... it justs dumps the deb in the screen in above script. Absence of  --print-uris is indeed a problem.

Comment: @Kusalananda By the way, apt-get of Ubuntu 16 does support --print-uris : http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/apt-get.8.html, so above script should work in Ubuntu as well. In any case, to install the package (either directly or via VM) just to see the man page, does not sound a handy idea. The worst case would be to use `apt-get download pkg` and then extract the man page from the downloaded deb (see updated code). The whole story is to built a GUI catalogue of available pkgs in repos (with a GUI search form) and then to provide the man page of any package with one click.

Comment: Based on this answer, here is a script to just download all the manpages from the repositories to your current directory. This will take quite a while and will consume a couple hundred megabytes of disk space once it is done, but it will allow you to simply browse these manpages with man just like any other manpage. https://gist.github.com/NuvandaPV/fc15eb998c305f8fc8123bf471971e79